# How to prove convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$a_n = n!/2^n$

Since $n!/2^n = 1/2 * 2/2 * 3/2 * ... * (n-1)/2 * n/2$

$1/2 <= n!/2^n$

I am having trouble finding an upper bound for the sequence.

Any hints or help is much appreciated in finding the upper bound of justifying why $a_n$ is unbounded?

Comment: You threw away too much; try $(n/2)(1/2)$, if $n>1$. (The sequence diverges to $\infty$.)

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $f(n)=\frac{n!}{2^n}$

$f(4)=\frac{4!}{2^4}=\frac{3}{2}>1$ for

$n\geq3$ we have $\frac{(n+1)!}{2^{n+1}}>2\frac{n!}{2^n}$.(since $n+1\geq4)$

So $f(n)\geq2f(n-1)$ for $n\geq 3$

since $f(4)\geq1$ we get $f(5)\geq2,f(6)\geq4,f(7)\geq 8\dots$